# Forms of being + past participle verb(v3) and difference between having + v3

Tags: passive-voice, past-participles

I read a lot of books to improve my english but sometimes I encounter some structures that are not found easily on learning webpages. First, I want to learn forms of being+V3(***v3 stands for past participle form of verbs***) **except by passive voice**. For example, I can't deduce the meaning of the sentence.

> Class `something` doesn’t enjoy any advantages by being defined in the same group or being a derived part.

I changed the above sentence to be understood. Here is original:

> Class `House` doesn’t enjoy any advantages by being defined in the same package or being a derived class.)

Second, I again really can't deduce meaning of sentences that use having+v3 structure **except by one that is at the beginning of a sentence. (i.e. having worked - After he had worked)** What are the forms of having+v3 and being+v3 except by I have just mentioned exceptions and short form of adjective clause.

Example sentences that I can't understand:

> It’s important to understand that there’s a difference between the practical knowledge of having worked with Java and the knowledge required to pass this certification exam.
>
> First, answer this question: do you remember having known more than one Amit, Paul, Anu, or John in your life?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Taking your last example first: do you understand the [*gerund* phrase](http://www.k12reader.com/term/gerund-phrase/)?  This is a phrase that begins with a gerund, where the -ing form of the verb acts like a noun.

> I enjoy (sitting on my roof)
>
> I remember (seeing the Beatles in concert)

In the same way "knowing ..." is a gerund phrase that is the object of "do you remember (X)?"

> Do you remember (knowing how to play the guitar)?

Take this and change it to the present perfect, which indicates a *life experience*:

> (I have known how to play the guitar.) Do you remember having known how to play the guitar?
>
> (I have worked with Java) Do you recall having worked with Java?

In a similar way, the "to be" verb "is" can be used as a gerund:

> (It is open) I remember it being open.
>
> (It is defined in the manual) It is no less confusing, even after being defined in the manual.

This syntax is convoluted and I personally don't recommend using it, if possible.  Most of these examples are better when written with simpler grammar:

> There is a difference between the practical knowledge you get from working in Java, and the knowledge required to pass this test.
>
> Have you known more than one Amit ... in your life?